# Injecting touch event?

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I'm a BlackBerry Java developer and I'm relatively new to BlackBerry 10 development.

Recently I wanted to make something involving touch events, and I was wondering whether any existing APIs exist for injecting touch events onto the screen. I looked around, and [native support apparently is scheduled for future release](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/downloads/roadmap/), however some have apparently achieved this using Qt. I have zero experience with Qt, so if anyone can provide some information on this (or even some pointers) I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you'd go about achieving this if support does not exist. What you might want to consider instead is to directly call the method in your controller that you've assigned as the slot for the signal of the touch event you're looking to emulate.

If you're separated your view and controller appropriately, there's no need to go full-hog and simulate the actual touch.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't want to simulate touch to invoke an event for a view. But since you said simulating touch isn't possible, I'll probably have to find another way to do so.